# Jenkins is not running under tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am facing strange issue.I am on `Redhat6`, `Jenkins 1.6`, `Java 1.6_45`and `maven 3.2.5`
I have deployed Jenkins under tomcat, and able t build two project.
when I type `localhost:8080/jenkins` I was able to access `jenkins` welcome page. It was working perfect. Today I restated my system ans started tomcat using command `./startup.sh`

```html
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/varun/app/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/varun/app/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/varun/app/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/varun/app/jdk1.6.0_45
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/varun/app/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/qaserver3/app/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

When I type in url `localhost:8080` I am getting the welcome page of tomcat.
It means my tocat is running perfectly.
now when I try to access Jenkins using `localhsot:8080/jenkins`
I get

```html
HTTP Status 404 - /jenkins/

type Status report

message /jenkins/

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
```

I have access `jenkins` thousand time like above. but I don't know what is wrong.
can any body help me.

Comment: In your Tomcat webapps folder, the jenkins app exists? Did you check the Tomcat contexts in the context.xml file?

Comment: Yes the jenkins app exists

Comment: In the Tomcat admin console, are you able to see your Jenkins app?

Comment: Problem is sorted out. I changed the java version  from 1.6.45 to 1.7. but, java version should not matter at all. I saw the documentation of Jenkins.http://jenkins-ci.org/content/good-bye-java6 . But i was working with java version 6. I dont know what is wrong. some time it works some time doesn't.

Comment: Cool if you find the solution :)